# Validation formula on new items only

Tags: list, column, validation

I'm using the following formula to prevent users from entering spaces on the article name field.

```
=ISERROR(FIND(" ",ArticleName))
```

The problem is the users have already entered data in this field prior to adding validation formula so the business owners want the validation formula to be implemented on new items only.

I know that I move my formula to the list validation settings however I'm having trouble combining 2 formulas.  Below is my latest attempt

```
=IF(Created = "",ISERROR(FIND(" ",ArticleName)),TRUE)
```

So what I thought I was doing is if `Created == Null` then perform the formula validation otherwise return a value of true.

So basically I want to perform my space check validation on new items only.  Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below formula

```
=OR(ISBLANK(Created),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Created)),ISERROR(FIND(" ",ArticleName))))
```

People can hack this approach by first creating without space and then editing with space. To eliminate this use case you can add more logic which uses CREATED is less than 10/22/2014

Comment: Hey Amal thanks for the help and it appears your solution might work but 1 thing.  

1. Is it possible to put some type of error message if the rule is violated?

Comment: Yes you can use the list validation page "User Message" text block for that.

Comment: I tried that but the form just refreshes instead of showing the message

Comment: It seems some javascript or other elements (CSS) is blocking the error message from getting displayed.

Comment: Oh well I guess the business user won't mind but I was wondering when I try to insert Created<"10/22/2014" like this 
=OR(ISBLANK(Created<"10/22/2014"),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Created<"10/22/2014")),ISERROR(FIND(" ",ArticleName))))

The validation doesn't work.  Why is that?

Comment: I tried using dateformat like so but got an error

=OR(ISBLANK(Created<DateFormat("10/22/2014",MM/DD/YYYY)),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Created<DateFormat("10/22/2014",MM/DD/YYYY)),ISERROR(FIND(" ",ArticleName))))