# Column Validation for new items only

Tags: sharepoint-server, validation, date

I have the following in the column validation on a SharePoint 2013 site

```
=[Load Date and Time]>=TODAY()
```

The above works well however I have a flaw in my logic!

I want users to be able to change other fields even if the date in the "Load Date and Time" field is in the past, however if they change the date field itself it must always be today or a future date.

How and where would I enforce this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ISBLANK(Created) to check whether the item is new one.

One thread for your reference

[Validation formula on new items only](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118847/validation-formula-on-new-items-only)

Update:

Try below formula which I tested.

```
=IF(Created=Modified,[Load Date and Time]>=TODAY(),TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I having difficulty with the syntax!
=OR(ISBLANK(Created), AND ([Load Date and Time]>=TODAY()))

Also tried:


=AND(ISBLANK(Created), [Load Date and Time]>=TODAY())

Comment: Try my updated formula

Comment: Fantastic THANK YOU